# Problem setting class path for java program

Tags: terminal, classpath, cp

I'm in the terminal trying to set my class path. I've done it before with a program that had no packages. This one does have a package and when i try to run it i get a noclassdeffound wrong name and then my package name
i then run it the same way but like this /d/g/j/l/myfile which is my package name and then it decides to just give me a generic noclassdeffound. any ideas on what is causing this?

Comment: what is in the stacktrace?  what is your classpath?  what jars are in your classpath?  what is in those jars?

Answer (score 0):

is the noclassdeffound referring to the actual class you try to execute?
If so, then it's simply not on the classpath.

Are you aware of the -cp command line option you can specify?

If these hints don't help, could you share more details please?